# networkx and folium generate different maps

Tags: python, networkx

I'm trying to generate a map with specific locations on it from a list.

I tried to do it with foluim package and networkx.
My data is a list with locations (lon,lat) which I used for both networkx and foluim.

The maps are after plotting the locations.

The foluim map look like:

[image]

and the networkx map:

[image]

The code is almost the same,
foluim code:

```
m = folium.Map(center_point)

for index in range(len(my_dict)):
    point = list(my_dict.keys())[index]
    lon = point[0]
    lat = point[1]
    loc = (lat, lon)
    folium.Circle(loc, popup=name, radius=2, color='black').add_to(m)
    folium.Circle(loc, popup=name, radius=600, color='crimson').add_to(m)
m.save('map.html')
```

and this is the networkx one:

```
for index in range(len(my_dict)):
    point = list(my_dict.keys())[index]
    lon = point[0]
    lat = point[1]
    ax.scatter(lon, lat, c='blue', s=60)

plt.show()
```

any ideas?

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: How is it possible that there are different resuts with the same locations list? implementation bugs of one of the packages? reading the map differently?

Comment: Can you clarify what you expected to see different?  These look very similar to me, except that the geographic areas they cover aren't exactly identical - the overlap is pretty large.

Comment: By the way, rather than `for index in range(len(my_dict)):
    point = list(my_dict.keys())[index]`, try   `for point in my_dict:`.  Usually in python you can avoid iterating by index, and it's usually easier to read the code if we do avoid it.

Comment: @Joel the map area is the same but the pinned location are different(red circle\blue dots) but the locations lat and lon are the same

Comment: So it would help to know what `my_dict` is.  I'm not familiar with folium, but what I'd be expecting from your networkx-ish code (which by the way, doesn't use networkx) that there would be a circle appearing at every single point in `my_dict`, since it's in the for loop.  So I'm unclear on why there were only 2 blue circles.

Comment: and - can you tell me what version of python you're running?  I'm wondering if your problem is that dicts don't guarantee consistent order.

Comment: @Joel my code use networkx and osmnx for generating some locations but not for the plotting stage. so there are more circles but I crop the map that the difference will be visible. I use python 3.7-pycharm and my dict is look like: {(lon1,la1t): cntr1 , (lon2,lat2): cntr2 ...} where cntr is the number of appearence of each location